# Generics - get properties LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics, propertyinfo

I have this class:

```
  private void Get_properties<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
  {

     List<string> longest_values = new List<string>(); 

     var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

     foreach (var prop in properties)
     {
        var prop_value = collection.OrderByDescending(y=> prop.GetValue(y,null)).FirstOrDefault();
   
        longest_values.Add(prop_value);
      }

      //Now I want to do something with this List
      foreach (var item in longest_values)
      {
         //..
      }

    }
```

I'm trying to find values of each property in collection that has longest string value, by LINQ. How can I do that?

Comment: There seems to be a separate question in the comment in your code: _"// returns only type name (e.g. My_project.Models.My_model)"_ - is that relevant to this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn´t work"? what dou expect? Of course `string.Join` has to transform your actual `Type` into some `string`-representation, which is done using `ToString`.

Comment: Do you want to print the actual values of the properties in descending order?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, print is just for testing purposes. What I need is the actual longest string value of each property from collection, to add It inside List<string>.

Comment: @Lucy82 Does that mean you actually only want to consider string properties as opposed to all properties?

Comment: @Lucy82 I'm still a little confused. Are all of your properties string properties? Or do you first need to exclude and properties that aren't strings?

Comment: your edit isn´t helpful at all. You still did not mention what you want to **achieve** with that code, nor what "not working" actually means. If all you want is your current **working** code to be transformed into LINQ, you have to provide that **working** code. How would you expect anyone here to guess what your problem actually is?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I am not a native speaker, so my words might not be fully understandable to all people, but someone - TheGeneral - seems to understood me. I have the answer, thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This will give you the "*first of the longest string of all properties for each item*"

Or said a different way. This will iterate through the generic list, get all the properties and their values (of which are string), then get the first value (order by descending by length)

```
var result = typeof(T)
   .GetProperties()
   .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
   .Select(prop => collection
      .Select(y => (string) prop.GetValue(y, null))
      .OrderByDescending(z => z.Length)
      .FirstOrDefault())
   .ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Original**

I think you were slightly off track with the `OrderByDescending` where you wanted a `Select` then orderby or orderby then select maybe? either way this will give you a list of values of properties in each object in the list

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
   var prop_values = collection.Select(y => prop.GetValue(y, null));
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", prop_values)); 
}
```

Comment: yes this gives me values, but how can I sort them? What I need Is only a single value from each property - longest string value of It.

Comment: @Lucy82 so you only want strings? and the first of the longest string of all properties for each item?

Comment: not exactly as you said. I need first of the longest string of each property. Item in collection are lists, so all lists in collection needs to be checked for property value and output longest one, that's It. I hope you understand :)

Comment: unbelievable, this is It :) I knew there has to be a trick using LINQ. Haven't thought about inner Select. Thanks for this, you really saved my day, I've been struggling with this for 2 days now !

Comment: @Lucy82 i know, i am awesome right? anyway good luck. Make sure when you ask  your next question to be a little more specific ;)

Comment: awesome is modest description :))...I'm sorry, I'll try to be more precise next time.

Answer (score -1):

Since prop_value is an `object`, you're calling `string.Join(string, parm object[])` with a single value, which would be equivalent to;

```cs
Console.WriteLine(prop_value?.ToString());
```

And the default `ToString()` method returns the type name of the object.